# Nginx app entrence forbidden although DB and CMS synced and DR dir permissions set

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash I've established LEMP and I can't access a WordPress app from browser although DB data is according (as I recall), and document root app dir has the right permissions (see below).

### Nginx conf

- [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c0ec022f7cd810d63fdb9db95cc0bc28) (all default).
- [nginx default](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c44ee73a167fa97ea8225dfffa056ca1) (all default).
- [Nginx app conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43a072589a9c41fc76924cd9e3397789) (seven first lines are mine - the rest is Certbot).

### WordPress app wp-config.php

This is the only part I changed in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'example.com');
define('DB_USER', 'example.com');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'example.password');
```

### My resets before testing

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w /var/www/html/
systemctl restart nginx.service
/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart
```

### Nginx logs

I checked all three Nginx logs (`-t`,`access` and `error`). The first two logs output no error, but `error` outputs this:

```
directory index of "/var/www/html/example.com/" is forbidden
```

### My question

Why is the entrance forbidden, given the above data? What I miss?

### Notes:

1. This problem is unique to the WordPress app. It doesn't happen with the non-HTTPS, PHPmyadmin app.
2. The DB user and the DB name of the WordPress app are identical to one another and also identical to the app's dir name.

Comment: Is there anything useful in your nginx error logs? (located `/var/log/nginx/error.log`)

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The server root at your [Nginxapp.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43a072589a9c41fc76924cd9e3397789) should be:

```
root /var/www/html;
```

Not:

```
root /var/www/html/example.com/;
```

BTW, this setting has been defined in the Nginx virtual machine [default.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c44ee73a167fa97ea8225dfffa056ca1), it is kind of redundant to redefine it again at the app conf file.

### Update

With your comment of not working after changing the root to `root /var/www/html;`, I further check your setting, and notice that you do not have a location directive for handling the root directory, try to change this line in your [virtual host setting](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c44ee73a167fa97ea8225dfffa056ca1) from:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this change didn't help: The entrance is still forbidden after this change.

Comment: `certbot --nginx -d "$domain" -d www."$domain"`

Comment: I updated my post, please take a look on my update regarding `location /` setting.

Comment: Please see my answer, dear hcheung.

Comment: Great to see it is working now. I think the parameters `/index.php?args;` or `/index.php?q=$uri&$args;` depend on your permalink setting on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with this conf:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/judith-law.co.il;
    server_name judith-law.co.il www.judith-law.co.il;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

 # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```